# How to read each new line from file after 10 second delay with Akka?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to read from file line by line with some delay.

For example:

- read and print 1st line of the file
- wait 10 seconds
- read and print 2nd line of the file
- etc

So far I have tried something like this:

```
final Path filePath = Paths.get('path/to/file');
final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Done>> printlnSink =
   Sink.<ByteString>foreach(chunk -> System.out.println(chunk.utf8String()));

final CompletionStage<IOResult> result = 
  FileIO.fromPath(filePath)
 .throttle(1, Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
 .to(printlnSink)
 .run(materializer);
```

But the this outbursts too many lines at a time and not one line at a time.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final CompletionStage<IOResult> result = 
 .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString(System.lineSeparator()),10000,FramingTruncation.ALLOW))
  FileIO.fromPath(filePath)
 .throttle(1, Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
 .to(printlnSink)
 .run(materializer);
```

See if that works for you, [framing Class](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Framing.html) documents should clarify

Comment: No problem! please accept the answer if that worked. happy new year